# NCurses build environment for Ada 2012 under Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: terminal, ada, ncurses, interactive

I have an upcoming Ada project (command-line interactive console program) and I would like to use something like ncurses to make screen management simpler.

I have installed the following packages (under Ubuntu 19.10 with latest updates):

- GNAT 8.3.0
- libncurses-dev
- libncursesada-dev
- libncursesada6.2.20180127
- libncursesada6.2.20180127-dev

In the "....../libncursesada-doc/examples/" directory there are quite a few demo programs, attempting to build any of them causes complaints such as:

```
$ gnatmake rain
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c rain.adb
rain.adb:44:06: file "terminal_interface.ads" not found
rain.adb:44:06: "Rain (body)" depends on "Ncurses2.Util (spec)"
rain.adb:44:06: "Ncurses2.Util (spec)" depends on "Terminal_Interface (spec)"
rain.adb:47:06: file "terminal_interface.ads" not found
gnatmake: "rain.adb" compilation error
```

Does this missing file indicate that this set of packages is broken or have I simply missed one out somewhere?

Or to put it another way, am I barking up the wrong tree with ncurses?  Is there a modern alternative that plays nicely with Ada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me on Debian 10.

GNAT version:

```
$ gnat --version
GNAT 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 1996-2018, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
  libncurses-dev \
  libncursesada-doc \
  libncursesada6.2.20180127 \
  libncursesada6.2.20180127-dev
```

Create a new dir:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir rain
$ cd ~/rain
```

Now build. In this case, we need to provide references to the source dirs using `-aI` (see also [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html#switches-for-gnatmake)) and link with `libncursesada` using `-largs -lncursesada` (see also [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html#mode-switches-for-gnatmake)):

```
$ gnatmake \
  -aI/usr/share/doc/libncursesada-doc/examples \
  -aI/usr/share/ada/adainclude/ncursesada \
  rain.adb \
  -largs -lncursesada
```

Comment: Splendid, the rain program works nicely.  This seems to work for the "ncurses.adb" demo too which seems to be a very comprehensive demonstration of the ncurses Ada binding.  I hope others find this useful.  Thank you for your help @DeeDee